# MySQL dual datestamp for modified, and updated does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, datestamp, mysql-error-1293

I am trying the following SQL statement:

```
create table sample (
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(100),
date_modified timestamp not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp,
date_created timestamp not null default now()
)
```

It's not working... I'm getting the following error:

```
#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

I need to keep track of two date stamps, one for the date the row was created and one for the date the row was last modified. They both do what I want I use them alone, but MySQL will not allow me to combine them in a single table.

Please help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create trigger `BEFORE UPDATE` and modify `date_modified` in it.

Or `BEFORE INSERT` and create `date_created` there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used:
CREATE TRIGGER creation_timestamp BEFORE INSERT ON `sample`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.date_created = NOW();

Comment: @kkarim: if my answer was helpful - you can check it with checkmark ;-)